# Couldn't Start apache2 server

Tags: server, permissions, apache2

I am getting the following errors while starting apache2 server-

```
The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/run/apache2': Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lock/apache2.26wFR2Eely': Operation not permitted
```

I used the following command-

```
sudo service apache2 start
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things to check

- do you have another apache instance running?

  ```
  ps aux | grep apache2
  ```

  to check if you have and

  ```
  pkill -9 apache
  ```

  and start apache again.
- if not check with ...

  ```
  ls -l /var/lock/apache2.26wFR2Eely
  ```

  the username and group of the file. The username and group need to match what you set apache up with. If not remove this file and start apache again.

Comment: How do I know whether another apache2 server is running or not, using the the command you have given? What should be result if an apache instance is running, and what if it is not? Please make it clear.

Comment: If it is running it will show a processnumber telling you if it does. If it does not it does not show  a process number. Do a `man ps` to read up on the command; it is something you need to know about when using apache, mysql and other server software.

Comment: cool! glad you got it working :-)

Comment: If I installed apache with `sudo apt install..` do I need to start apache as root and not normal user?

Comment: You start it with sudo. sudo service apache start.